# Slice string number and remove zero

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I've got a string number '00:00:00.0500000' how to receive '00:00:00.50'
Which of the method to us, I'm not flexible with regex 
I want 2 digit after '.' , and also I don not know to how much zeros I have after 5

Comment: Do you want the last part (after the `.`) to be 2 digits long? How would you convert `.12345`? Give us some examples.

Comment: simply `'00:00:00.0500000'.substring(0,11) `

Comment: `.50` or `.05`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```js
let str = '00:00:00.0500000';

str = str.replace(/0+$/, '');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: In case if I don't not how much zeros I have after 5